# GNU Make using : syntax

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Working with this simple code, can someone explain how are the last two lines compiled

```
PROJECT_NAME     := PRJ
TARGETS          := nrf52840_xxaa
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY := _build

SDK_ROOT := ../nRF5_SDK_17.1.0_ddde560

$(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/nrf52840_xxaa.out: \
  LINKER_SCRIPT  := Core/PRJ.ld
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last two lines don't specify any build rule, but instead specify a [target-specific variable value](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) for the target `$(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/nrf52840_xxaa.out` and the variable `LINKER_SCRIPT`. The build rule is either specified elsewhere, or a default build rule is used.